# Protractor - select the second or third element at the same level

Tags: protractor

I know that there are some questions-answers similar to the topic but mine is a bit different.

I also know that we have functions like first() and last() in Protractor but I'm wondering whether it's possible to to something what is possible in regular Webdriver like:

```
//div[@attr='header']/div/div[2]
```

Where you can indicate the second sibling by   [2] ?
I've tried that and didn't work but maybe here it looks a bit differently?

Comment: Can you add some html to your question to make it a little easier to understand what you are asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of different ways to accomplish this. Along the same lines of using `.last()` and `.first()`, you can also use `.get(<index>)`. Indexes start at 0. So `element.all(by.xpath('//div[@attr='header']/div/div').get(2)` would work for this scenario.

You can also use `:nth-child()` css selector to find siblings. Indexes for `nth-child` start at 1.

```
<div>
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
</div>
```

In the above html snippet, if I wanted to select the 3rd span I would use `'div > span:nth-child(3)'`